# Extract two url occurrences in a pandas field of strings

Tags: python, pandas

So given this example Series

```
s = pd.Series(["Redirecting (301) to <GET http://www.vix.com/pt/mulher> from <GET http://www.vix.com/pt/bolsademulher>'",
               "Redirecting (307) to <GET https://twibbon.com/> from <GET http://twibbon.com/>'"])
```

I am able to extract the first url like this:

```
s.str.extract('(https?://[^>]+)', expand=True)
```

But I would like to extract both urls, each to a different column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s.str.extractall('(https?://[^>]+)').unstack()
```